# BigInteger copying

Tags: java, biginteger

Maybe I'm really confused because it seems a very simple question but Google and the official documentation were not enough.

I want to copy an BigInteger, and I can't find a clean way of doing it. `BigInteger a = b` when `b` is a BigInteger, as BigInteger is an object and there's no operator overloading here, `a` references to the same object as `b`

The cleanest way I've found so far is `BigInteger a = b.add(BigInteger.ZERO)`, but still a dirty way for me.

Comment: `BigInteger a = new BigInteger(b)`?

Comment: `BigInteger` is immutable. Any specific reason for needing a copy ?

Comment: It's immutable, why do you need a copy?

Comment: @Jon [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) doesnt seem to have a copy constructor

Comment: BigInteger a = b; should work, is there a particular problem or error you're having?

Comment: That's the point, it's inmutable, I didn't notice, thanks a lot!

I know it's in the documentation, in fact, it's the first word of the main text, but somehow I managed to ignore it :(

@JamesPoulson make it an answer if you want it scored.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BigInteger` is immutable like other wrapper classes such as `Integer` and `String`. So no worries about possible alteration/tampering.

P.S: As a bonus, here's a link on when defensive copying is needed.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15

Answer (score 16):

`BigInteger` is immutable -- there should never be any need to copy a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`BigInteger(String val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29)

```
BigInteger first = new BigInteger("15");
BigInteger second = new BigInteger(first.toString());
```

Although this is possible, `BigInteger` objects are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and I can't imagine a need to copy.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you shouldn't need to copy a `BigInteger` because it is immutable class.  (Copying a `BigInteger` is about as useful as copying a `String` ... )

But if you do need to copy one, then a more efficient way to do it would be this:

```
BigInteger first = new BigInteger(42);
BigInteger second = first.add(BigInteger.ZERO);
```

This avoids the (relatively) expensive binary -> decimal -> binary conversions and the creation of an intermediate string.

And `BigInteger.clone()` should be more efficient still ...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
BigInteger a = b.clone()
```

But as mentioned it's immutable so there should be no need.

Comment: think clone() is a protected method of BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

The immutability doesn't solve this problem:
Suppose you want to write a loop equivalent to

```
int a = 10;
for(int i = a; i < 10; i++){...}
```

with BigIntegers.
The initial value in a will be needed later on:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(10);
for(BigInteger i = a.copy(); a.compare(BigInteger.TEN) < 0; i = i.plus(BigInteger.ONE)
{...}
```

The initialization of the loop variable i will need a (nonexistent) copy operation,
since otherwise i and a would point to the same object and the value
in a would be lost once i is increased within the loop.

My best guess on an efficient way to do the copying would be something like

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(a.getByteArray());
```

(As has been noted before, e.g.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208304/21446284