# Making BigInteger equal another BigInteger variable in Java

Tags: java

I'm wondering is there a way to change a BigInteger variable's value to another BigInteger's value? It seems like 'BigInteger.valueOf' doesn't accept other BigIntegers as its value and neither does 'new BigInteger'.

Comment: Isn't `BigInteger` immutable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't read your question carefully enough.

> I'm wondering is there a way to change a BigInteger variable's value to another BigInteger's value

No, since BigInteger is immutable.

However, you can create a new BigInteger instance that would have the same value as the original :

One way is to convert to String and construct the copy from that String :

```
BigInteger source = ...
BigInteger target = new BigInteger (source.toString());
```

Another way is to use the byte array :

```
BigInteger target = new BigInteger (source.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I think it's the only way, unless you assign the reference to another `BigInteger`. There doesn't seem to be a way to mutate the object itself with a new value.

Comment: @Mena  What about using `toByteArray`?

Comment: nice one too! Learning new stuff today.

Answer (score 4):

BigInteger is inmutable you can't change the value.

```
old = new BigInteger( newValue );
```

Further reading:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

**EDIT**

To assign from other BigInteger yo can use:

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("0").add(oldValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 BigInteger a = new BigInteger("10");
 BigInteger b = new BigInteger(a.toString());
 System.out.println(b);
```